# MQ: How does MQ client knows to get the right response message

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I am newbie to Websphere MQ and i have some basic understanding on the concept of MQ. I know that MQ client would create a message (with MQMD and application data) and then send to MQ manager. MQ client will get the correct response back from MQ Manager. Supposedly there are many messages on the MQ Queue Manager, how does MQ client able to retrieve the right messages? What determines the uniqueness of a MQ message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways this can be approached - one common way is for the applications processing the messages to use the message ID and correlation ID fields.  The message ID can be randomly generated and saved then copied to correlation ID field to be match when the reply is sent.  Applications can do gets matching on those fields in the message header.

I suggest you read through the application [programming guide](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q002330_.htm) and [reference](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q002340_.htm) in the knowledge center.

Comment: Thanks so much :O)